# How to split string by forward slash in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2012, substring

There is no default split function in SQL Server 2012 that I'm using.

I want to split the string (ex: `/Folder1/Folder2/`) by `/`.

- if string is `/Folder1/` then output should be `Folder1`,
- if string is `/Folder1/Folder2/` then output should be `Folder2`,
- if string is `/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/` then output should be `Folder3`.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you on?

Comment: @Reno Sql server 2012

Comment: A combination of the [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions will get you there.

Comment: This question has been answered before in many different flavours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x?rq=1

Comment: @TT I found the answer with your help `SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(REVERSE('/Folder1/Folder2/'),2,len(REVERSE('/Folder1/Folder2/'))),1,charIndex('/',SUBSTRING(REVERSE('/Folder1/Folder2/'),2,len(REVERSE('/Folder1/Folder2/'))))-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl table (path varchar(100));
insert into @tbl values
('/Folder1/'),
('/Folder1/Folder2/'),
('/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/');

select *, 
       replace(substring(path, len(path) - charindex('/', reverse(path), 2) + 1, 1000), '/', '')
from @tbl
```